# How Long Can Same-Page Anchor Links (#) Be?

Tags: xhtml, anchor, long-integer, xhtml-transitional

What is the maximum number of characters that a same-page anchor tag link can be on all mainstream platform browsers released from IE6 on up?

For instance, a link like:

```
http://example.com/#a789c4d8ecb0ec2201444bfa64b04696aa2bbaa41eb331535d1dd6d219558a02968d5af97ae74359973163337ef9b09c65dd70d40c3c79a4169355ea92db45e21fe30550dce4987987237652a347b97759f2753b412ee50d4121d0f6382580b5a62d1e02921c39c252c5e4731e38fc295ad6abcb22613513c4fd7599ab10d3f9c970b9eb3ddf5b2cf233af25005298590ce798b28092cecdc6756c8205e9a0650826e42a184267d0bfb5e3d7b3d1c25e324fe6329cf7681ffae7c01c86d4a70
```

Note the # symbol above.

Note I'm using XHTML transitional, if that matters any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better question is "how long can my url be?"

Unfortunately, we must build to the weakest link, internet explorer, which limits the url to about 2000 characters.

So, the max length you can use on an anchor tag would be:
length of anchor = 2000 - (size of url)